# AngularJs Transclude with ng-repeat and multi transclude

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I want to user directive inside `ng-repeat` of other directive with transclusion.

I am able to user multitransclude outside of ng-repeat, however I want `<comment-popover>` to be inside of `<comment>` directives ng-repeat region. Here is my code.

Note: I can not use `<ng-transclude>`, as my comment directive will be used by other part of the application, where i wont have popover child directive

Here is my code link: https://codepen.io/waghanil87/pen/PmORLL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to define the transclusion that you want only in one section as optional?

```
transclude: {
  'mandatory': 'mandatory',
  'optional': '?optional'
}
```